# AutoHotKey: How to remap degree symbol(°) to backslash?

Tags: windows, autohotkey

I've got a keyboard which i guess doesn't align properly with the input language i use on Windows, so the key that is supposed to print a backslash prints the degree symbol (°) instead.

The funky part is that it doesn't work like a normal key - for the symbol to appear you must press another key.

How could i remap this key to print a backslash with AHK?

Comment: Sounds like you need to change your keyboard layout settings in Windows. (By the way, the "must press another key" thing is called a [dead key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_key).)

Comment: If you are talking about Fn keys or something similar, they have different VK or SC for each manufacturer. What you need to do is install a keyboard hook, then look into key history for your key. I am not sure if this remap would be directly transferrable to other computer.

Comment: Take a look at https://autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm#SpecialKeys

Comment: @melpomene There is no appropriate keyboard layout in windows for my keyboard + language! If only it were so easy... It's either having a proper backslash key or having language-specific special symbols.

Comment: @Crimson7 Thank you! I've found what I needed in order to set this script up!

Comment: @Darksworm You can create custom keyboard layouts if you want to.

Comment: @melpomene with the windows keyboard layout creation tool from 2007? I couldn't get it working on my windows 10 machine.

Comment: Ah, haven't tried Win 10 yet. I know it works on 7.

Comment: @melpomene well spoiler alert, it doesn't :^) anyway a custom layout would be a WAY better solution for anyone on windows 7

Answer (score 0):

In the end i set up a keyboard hook, looked at the pressed key code in Key history and mapped the SC code to print a backslash.
In the end the code was:

```
SC02B:: Send, \
```

The fact that the key originally was a dead key made no difference.